# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvDetails.Rows)
     {
         //Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
         CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
         //Condition to check checkbox selected or not
         if (chkdelete.Checked)
         {
             //Getting UserId of particular row using datakey value
             int usrid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value);

             using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=murugan-pc;Initial Catalog=rg_lava_software;User ID=sa;Password=123"))
             {
                 con.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from emp where empid=" + usrid, con);
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 con.Close();
             }
         }
     }
     BindUserDetails();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please format your code and elaborate your question.

Comment: Do I count one bracket too many in your code?

Comment: @boisvert Yes, you did.